# How to validate "Logging" to Android application using SMS validation

Tags: android, validation, sms

Before logging to android Application I want to enter my number and press Button.
This button handled to send SMS to the number enteres, so if the message received to me it will enter the application, else it will show a message to validate/verify the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Using the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver

`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
    {

    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[0]);
     Log.i(TAG,  msgs.getMessageBody());
    Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.uba.messagereceived");
    str = "SMS From "+msgs.getOriginatingAddress()+":"+msgs.getMessageBody().toString()+"...";
    intent2.putExtra("letter", str);
    intent2.putExtra("address", msgs.getOriginatingAddress());
    intent2.putExtra("txt", msgs.getMessageBody().toString());
    context.sendBroadcast(intent2);

    } 
    //---display the new SMS message---
    Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(yMsg == msgg &&  xNum == no)
    {
    setStatus("valid");
    Intent mp = new Intent(context,UserMainPage.class);
    context.startActivity(mp );
    Toast.makeText(context,"The Validation completed: "+this.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 

else
    {
    setStatus("not Valid");
    Toast.makeText(context,"The Validation completed: "+this.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
```

`